# ldirectord process disappears

Tags: ldirectord

I have 2 frontend apache webservers that are load balanced using **ldirectord**.  ldirectord is kept running on one server or the other by **heartbeat**

Recently I upgraded these servers from Debian Etch to Debian Lenny

Ever since then, every once-in-a-while, the ldirectord process disappears, however, load balancing appears to keep working.  Page http://webserver/server-status shows connections being served on both servers, even while there is no ldirectord process running.

**Can anyone explain what is going on here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ldirectord is the app to administer load balancing, it doesn't do the balancing. once settings are transferred to the kernel they will stay until changed again or the server is rebooted.

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

You can see the loadbalancing state by `ipvsadm -L -n`. ldirectord is only a frontend for ip_vs module in kernel.

ldirectord should run on the primary node (which have the shared IP address)